Author Name missing/wrong in Commit besides correct config
Whenever I create a commit in git, the author name is set to y for some reason e.g.
commit a9d8e57d15asdfb06865858fa6dsdsfd4ae42850d5d83
"Author: Y "
Date:   Mon Jun 3 14:13:27 2024 +0500
Wrong Author Name
I have the correct settings in the global config:
git config --global user.email
Mr.Mango@Tastsy.com

git config --global user.name
Mr Mango

Seems like git is unable to read the configuration.
The installed git version is: 2.45.2.windows.1

Does this happen in all repositories or only in a single repository? What is the output of git config --get-regexp 'user\.'?

Happens in all the repositories and the output is nothing.
